# Converting DateTime.Now to value which is friendly in setting the minimum scale of a chart

Tags: excel, vb.net, datetime, charts

I have some code which creates a chart in excel. The x-axis is in a date format and as a standard excel setup the autoscale always leaves a large gap before the data starts. To get round this I want my first date value to be the time right this second and set this as the .MinimumScale, but I'm getting problems and can't convert it into the right format.

For example the DateTime.Now value right now is 14/12/2017 14:25 and as a number in excel it's 43083.60. I think (although I'm not 100% sure) I need that value to input into my .MinimumScale

```
With chartPage.Axes(Excel.XlAxisType.xlValue)
            .HasTitle = True
            .AxisTitle.Caption = "Time (Days)"
            .hasminorgridlines = True

            Dim date1 As String
            date1 = DateTime.Now.ToString

            MessageBox.Show(date1)
            .MinimumScale = date1
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excel stores date-time values as a `Double` data type.  The [Axis.MinimumScale Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/axis-minimumscale-property-excel) is also of type `Double`.

To convert a .Net `DateTime` value to a `Double` that represents an Excel DateTime value, call its [ToOADate Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tooadate(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
.MinimumScale = DateTime.Now.ToOADate()
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks for the response!